# Numeric only Javascript form Validation?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Can't seem to get this function to work for some reason, read about 10000 documents lol

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you *using* that function?

Comment: So sorry, it's used to validate entries before submitting it to an sql database, with an alert

Comment: do you want just positive integers? positive and negative? floating point numbers as well? scientific notation?

Comment: I understand that. I meant, in your code on your page, how and where is that function called?

Comment: Change `if(inputtxt.value.match(numbers))` to `if(!numbers.test(inputtxt.value))` which will match non numbers

Comment: onsubmit='return validateMyForm()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a bit of poor logic with your if statement for numbers. As I mentioned in the comment

`if(inputtxt.value.match(numbers))` should be

```
if(!numbers.test(inputtxt.value)) {
      alert('Please input numeric characters only');
      document.reasoning.mpn.focus();
      isValid = false;
}
```

For your document you're trying to validate fields with `mpn` name but you're not retrieving them as far as I can see. Seeing there is only 1 mpn field you may want to use an id so you dont have to iterate as below. Try the following:

```
isValid = isValid && all(document.getElementsByName("mpn"), function(ele) {
   if(numbers.test(ele.value)) {
       return true;
   } else {
       alert('Please input numeric characters only');
       ele.focus()
       return false;
   }
});
```

I don't feel like typing out the code for `all` but assume its something like `_.all` from underscorejs.

Comment: Thank you very much Megawac for your response, i have updated the question with the code you supplied but for some reason it just submits the data without any warning (when entering non-numeric characters), thanks!

Comment: Does `inputtxt` refer to the correct element? Can you set up a jsfiddle if code continues not working

Comment: Updated but that fiddle doesnt work as the validateForm function is not defined when it's added to the input.